# How to properly write down network gear documentation?

Tags: networking, documentation

I've "inherited" the network in my office recently, and I'd like to put black on white about all the networking gear, and I want to do it "the right way". We have managed switches, VLANs, LAGs,  hypervisors, VMs for LAN services (internal DNS, DHCP, Firewall...) and so on.

My first attempt was to write down multiple spreadsheets and list there all the IP addresses in use by "special" hardware (eg server/VM/switch), their root/administration passwords, and all other useful stuff. But I realize this is not the best way to document the status of the network.

Then I tried to "draw" the logical network with simple tools like [draw.io](https://www.draw.io). This is a nice way of seeing the network, but I don't know if the efforts are worth it.

The question is: how to write all this stuff properly?

Comment: This might not have one answer - it is partly a matter of taste and partly related to the kind of information you want to capture and what your resources are. And you're not going to get it all in one document. I use one spreadsheet for passwords, another one for IP addresses, a spreadsheet AND a Visio diagram for VLANs, another diagram for physical connections, the VLAN diagram gets router IPs and DHCP scopes on it also, plus there's rack elevations and service maps and I really don't have a way I like to document firewall rules. So yeah. All that.